# Add version.txt file from jenkins in JAR using maven project

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to add a simple text file from Jenkins build pipeline which contains below details

```
{
    "app name": "service_1",
    "branch name": "git branch name",
    "build date": "date",
    "git revision": "xyz",
}
```

I am able to generate this file from jenkins with all details but its not the part of the jar so is there any way we can make it part of the generated .JAR file.
So that jenkins generated artefact will have a single .JAR file including version.txt.
I will be creating an endpoint to read this version.txt file to check which version and branch is currently deployed on the server.

Comment: What did you try to make it a part of jar? Did you copy it into resources before launching maven? Alternative approach would be resource filtering.

Comment: Achieved this by using maven resource filtering. Passed build details as parameters using maven goal in jenkins job which updates the build.properties file in target folder. Then created an endpoint to read that file and return build info in json as output.